# powershell compress files within subfolder and over certain age

Tags: powershell, zip, compression, 7zip

I have been looking around for several hours on this issue. I am looking for some help to fix this script. The Script is to search the shared folder for files in sub-folders and zip the folder up in that sub folder. What I need to also do is add the last access time of the files or folder so I can set an age to it such as 1 year or 365 days. Then 7z  would remove the file after compression saving space on the server for other things.

So c:\share
c:\share\folder1 
c:\share\folder2
c:\share\folder3
etc...

the script in my testing is like this

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   <A brief description of the script>
.DESCRIPTION
   <A detailed description of the script>
.PARAMETER <paramName>
   <Description of script parameter>
.EXAMPLE
   <An example of using the script>
#>

#Compress all the files based on your folder structure
Set-Location -Path 'c:\shared'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\shared' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
    $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
    $directoryName = $_.Name
    Invoke-Expression -Command 'C:\7-Zip\7z.exe a "-x!*.zip" -sdel $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip $directoryFullName\*'
}
```

I am trying this below but getting an error I do not understand yet as to formatting property.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
   <A brief description of the script>
.DESCRIPTION
   <A detailed description of the script>
.PARAMETER <paramName>
   <Description of script parameter>
.EXAMPLE
   <An example of using the script>
#>

#Compress all the files based on your folder structure
Set-Location -Path 'c:\shared'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\shared' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer $_.LastWriteTime -gt "01-01-1900" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-365) } | ForEach-Object {
    $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
    $directoryName = $_.Name
    Invoke-Expression -Command 'C:\7-Zip\7z.exe a "-x!*.zip" -sdel $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip $directoryFullName\*'
}
```

here is the error

```
At C:\Users\HarrelsonNetworks\Documents\windowspowershell\Scripts\testbackup3.ps1:14 char:75
+ ... Path 'c:\shared' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer $_.LastWri ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '$_' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

thanks

for your help

jharl

Comment: What is $_.PSIsContainer doing there? It's not part the condition for Where-Object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following: 1. Create a temp folder 2. MOVE (not copy) everything you want over to the temp folder 3. Zip the temp forder and save to desired location 3. delete the temp folder.

Breaking it out into steps like this will let you work through the problem better.

Here is something similar I wrote recently, it doesn't solve your problem but it should point you in the right direction:

```
function archiveLogs ( [string]$OriginalLocation, [string]$NewLocation ){

## Age of files to be archived
$DeleteOlderThan = 30

# Create temp folder to store files to be archived
New-Item c:\Temp\_tempfolder -type directory
# Get all children of specific directory older than 'X' days and of ".log" file type and move to temp folder
get-childitem -Path $OriginalLocation\*.log |
    where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-$DeleteOlderThan)} | 
    move-item -destination "C:\Temp\_tempfolder" 

## Zip all .log files in temp folder and save to '$NewLocation\(DATE)_Archive'
& "C:\temp\7za.exe" a -tzip $NewLocation\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm'))_Archive -r c:\Temp\_tempfolder\*.log
## Delete temp folder
Remove-Item c:\temp\_tempfolder -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Goodluck and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: thanks this is for a share cleanup. zips need to maintain directory structure and prune old files older then x. I don't have time to tear thru 2 TB of data. this script was working with only $_.PSIsContainer and I new I had to add some date controls. but they are not working. will keep pounding on it monday thanks jack

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the logical operator `-and`. To resolve the error, change:

```
{$_.PSIsContainer $_.LastWriteTime -gt "01-01-1900" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-365) }
```

To:

```
{$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt "01-01-1900") -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-365)) }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, fixed the script as per instruction and I enter the command and it just returns to the ps prompt weird, no messages.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\shared' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).Addyears(-2))} | ForEach-Object {
 $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
 $directoryName = $_.Name
 Invoke-Expression -Command 'C:\7-Zip\7z.exe a "-x!*.zip" -sdel $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip $directoryFullName\*'

Comment: got rid of the ($_.LastWriteTime -gt "01-01-1900") changed (get-date).addyears(-2) script runs but still zips everything not as expected, but all files get zipped. need 2 years of working data, the drive goes back 10 years. need to save some $pace when it goes up to the cloud.